# Code academy error (confused) ^^

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I would like to know why this code gives the message: SyntaxError: unexpected token else.

```
var compare = function(choice1,choice2){
if(choice1===choice2){
    return("The result is a tie!");
}else if(choice1==="rock"){
    if(choice2==="scissors"){
        return("rock wins");
    }else{
        return("paper wins");
    }else if(choice1==="paper"){
        if(choice2==="rock"){
            return("paper wins");
        }
    }  
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `else if` should be **before** `else`, like this:

```
var compare = function(choice1,choice2){
if(choice1===choice2){
    return("The result is a tie!");
}else if(choice1==="rock"){
    if(choice2==="scissors"){
        return("rock wins");
    }else if(choice1==="paper"){
        if(choice2==="rock"){
            return("paper wins");
        }
    } else{
        return("paper wins");
    } 
}
```

Comment: You mean "before"?   :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an `else if` after the `else`, so it's getting tripped up.

It should be

```
if(choice2==="scissors"){
    return("rock wins");
} else if(choice1==="paper"){
    if(choice2==="rock"){
        return("paper wins");
    }
} else{
    return("paper wins");
}
```

If statements always start with an `if`, then the `else if`s, and then finally the `else`. Everything but the first `if` is optional, but the order always needs to be the same.